# Rules to set hyper-parameters alpha and theta in LDA model

Tags: lda, gensim

I will like to know more about whether or not there are any rule to set the hyper-parameters alpha and theta in the LDA model. I run an LDA model given by the library `gensim`:

```
ldamodel = gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel(corpus, num_topics=30, id2word = dictionary, passes=50, minimum_probability=0)
```

But I have my doubts on the specification of the hyper-parameters. From what I red in the library documentation, both hyper-parameters are set to 1/number of topics. Given that my model has 30 topics, both hyper-parameters are set to a common value 1/30. I am running the model in news-articles that describe the economic activity. For this reason, I expect that the document-topic distribution (theta) to be high (similar topics in documents),while the topic-word distribution (alpha) be high as well (topics sharing many words in common, or, words not being so exclusive for each topic). For this reason, and given that my understanding of the hyper-parameters is correct, is 1/30 a correct specification value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll assume you expect theta and phi (document-topic proportion and topic-word proportion) to be closer to equiprobable distributions instead of sparse ones, with exclusive topics/words.

Since alpha and beta are parameters to a symmetric Dirichlet prior, they have a direct influence on what you want. A Dirichlet distribution outputs probability distributions. When the parameter is 1, all possible distributions are equally liked to outcome (for K=2, [0.5,0.5] and [0.99,0.01] have the same chances). When parameter>1, this parameter behaves as a pseudo-counter, as a prior belief. For a high value, equiprobable output is preferred (P([0.5,0.5])>P([0.99,0.01]). Parameter<1 has the opposite behaviour. For big vocabularies you don't expect topics with probability in all words, that's why beta tends to be under 1 (the same for alpha).

However, since you're using Gensim, you can let the model learn alpha and beta values for you, allowing to learn asymmetric vectors (see [here](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/ldamodel.html)), where it stands

> alpha can be set to an explicit array = prior of your choice. It also
>   support special values of ‘asymmetric’ and ‘auto’: the former uses a
>   fixed normalized asymmetric 1.0/topicno prior, the latter learns an
>   asymmetric prior directly from your data.

The same for eta (which I call beta).